# Given a machine that can sort 5 of your objects. How fast can we sort 25 of them?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

> Assume that, you have **25 objects**, and  a **machine that can sort 5 of them** by some criteria that you don't even know. The cost of using this machine is very expensive (1$ for one launch), so what is the minimal cost of sorting all of your objects?

My current solution is very simple (similar idea to [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)):

1. Randomly divide them into 5 groups of 5 objects
2. Sort each of them (+5 launches)
3. Now, sort the minimal elements of these five groups (+1 launch)
4. Now we have the minimal element of the whole set. Remove it from the group that it's belong to, and repeat the step **3** until only 5 unsorted objects left in general (+19 launch)
5. Sort the rest 5 objects (+1 launch)

So, in general, we have to pay **26$** (26 launches).

> Question: Is there any way to make it cheaper (sort them in the least number of launches)?

Comment: Log_5! 25! = 12.1 so it takes at least 13 sorts.

Comment: @DouglasZare Oh, you're right, I hurried a bit accepting the solution. Btw, why `log( 5! 25! )`? Can you please give me a link to this theorem?

Comment: Why not unselect the answer, and wait until there is actually a solution? log_5! 25! = log 25!/log 5!. It's the logarithm of 25! base 5!. There are only 5! ways to sort 5 objects, so if you only sort 12 times, you only get 5!^12 possible results, which is not enough to produce all 25! possible orderings.

Comment: Here is a related question on the math research site by a Fields medalist, which makes me think that this problem is tough and has been studied before, whether or not it has been solved: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92176/best-known-constant-for-parallel-sorting

Comment: It is not clear what "machine can sort 5 objects" mean: either return 5 objects in sorted order or report the permutation that would sort the objects. Solution in OP and both answers assume the latter. But is it really so?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Actually the question does not say "return permutation" anywhere; it says, "sort objects." I think that means it "sorts the objects." Is that kind of like those questions where you have two empty jugs of size 5 and 3 liters and you're supposed to pour 4?

Comment: @Evgeny Kluev: What alternative are you considering?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev It is the second variant - report the permutation that would sort the objects. In this case we will have more information :D

Comment: @EvgenyKluev  I'm assuming that the objects can be *identified*. That is, when you put them into the machine, and receive the sorted objects back, then you implicitly have the sorting permutation. So that "sorting the objects" and "returning the sorting permutation" are equivalent in terms of the information that is provided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a greedy algorithm for choosing which objects to sort at each iteration:

Sorting 25 objects a<sub>i</sub> is the same as completely filling a table M<sub>25x25</sub>, where M<sub>i,j</sub> = 1 if a<sub>i</sub> > a<sub>j</sub>, and –1 otherwise. After you perform a single iteration of sorting with the machine, you get immediate relations between the elements you have just sorted (up to 5 cells immediately filled), but after that you can fill more cells using commutativity (i.e. if a > b, then you know that b < a) and transitivity (i.e., if a > b and b > c, then you know that a > c).

To select 5 elements for the next sorting, you choose the elements, for which there are most empty cells in the intersections between rows and columns corresponding to those elements. For that you can just compare all possible combinations. There are 25 choose 5 = 53130 possible variants, and the complexity is actually exponential, but that doesn't cost any "money" in this problem.

When the table is completely filled, you can build the sorted sequence with [Topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), or simply by sorting elements by the sum of the values in the the corresponding table row: the higher the sum, the larger the element.

This is not ideal, but quite effective. I've tested this method on random permutations and the result is about 16.8$ on average. Here is a code sample in Python:

```
import random
import itertools


class SortingMachine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.coins = 0

    def sort(self, elements):
        assert(len(elements) == 5)
        self.coins += 1
        return list(sorted(elements))


def test_sorting(seq):
    N = len(seq)
    machine = SortingMachine()
    table = [[0 if i == j else None for j in range(N)] for i in range(N)]

    # Fill empty table cells using transitivity with Floyd-Warshall algorithm
    def fill_transitive():
        for k in range(N):
            for i in range(N):
                for j in range(N):
                    if table[i][j] is None and table[i][k] == table[k][j]:
                        table[i][j] = table[i][k]

    # Register in the table the information that seq[i] > seq[j]
    def set_greater(i, j):
        table[i][j] = 1
        table[j][i] = -1

    # Register in the table information from 5 sorted elements
    def register_sorted(sub):
        for (el1, i1), (el2, i2) in zip(sub, sub[1:]):
            set_greater(i2, i1)

    # Select 5 elements to send to the machine
    def choose_elements():
        # Count empty cells in the cells corresponding to 5 comb elements
        def empty_cells(comb):
            return sum(table[i][j] is None 
                       for i, el1 in comb for j, el2 in comb)
        comb = max((empty_cells(comb), comb) 
                   for comb in itertools.combinations(enumerate(seq), 5))[1]
        return [(el, ind) for ind, el in comb]

    # Return True if the table is completely filled
    def is_complete():
        return all(all(el is not None for el in row) for row in table)

    while not is_complete():
        chosen = choose_elements()
        sorted_chosen = machine.sort(chosen)
        register_sorted(sorted_chosen)
        fill_transitive()

    # Checking that the sorting is correct
    sorted_seq = list(sorted(seq))
    assert(all(sorted_seq.index(seq[ind]) == (sum(row) + N - 1) // 2 
               for ind, row in enumerate(table)))

    return machine.coins


def random_sequence():
    l = list(range(25))
    random.shuffle(l)
    return l
```

The greedy heuristic in this method maximizes only the immediate information gained from the sort, without accounting for transitivity. Now, theoretically a better heuristic is to maximize the expected information the sorting of the 5 chosen elements gives, including all the information gained by transitivity. That is, choose 5 elements, with the maximum average (over all possible sorting outcomes of them) number of filled cells after considering transitivity. But the naive algorithm to implement that will take much longer to compute.

Comment: I've also have a thought about increasing the number of connections between vertices (if we assume that each element is a node in graph).  
In your algorithm: how do you think, what if instead of choosing 5 elements with the most empty cells, we choose 4 elements with most emty cells and 1 element with large number of non-empty cells and that is not comparable (yet) with those 4? In that case, we can fill more cells in one launch, thus we can fill the table faster, right?

Comment: @FalconUA I think that's what it's basically doing now, isn't it? It chooses 5 elements with the least empty cells with *each other*. Basically elements which haven't been compared with each other yet, and for which we know as little about their relation to each other as possible. And the better way I'm discussing in the last paragraph is to choose elements which will also give as much as possible information about other elements as well.

Comment: a > b ⇒ b ≤ a, while you're at it

Comment: @greybeard That's true, but the assumption is that all elements are different. That is, for any two elements, the machine would consistently return that one is greater than the other. That algorithm may not work otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

You are clearly not using the information very well. Lets say A1, B1, C1, D1, E1 are the smallest in their groups and you just found that D1 was the smallest overall. You then sort A1, B1, C1, D2 and E1. This is clearly inefficient since you know the order of four of these.

Lets say they came out in order D1, A1, C1, E1, B1. You removed D1. Which items can be the smallest ones? Only A1 and D2. Which items can be the second smallest ones? Only A1, C1, D2, D3 and A2. So you sort these five, and the two smallest ones are the smallest ones overall.

After that, the situation is a bit complicated, but we can definitely find the largest one, then the two next largest, then again the next largest and so on, so we have five initial sorts, 14 more sorts to find the 21 smallest, and one final sort = 20 total. We can probably do better, but then it gets complicated.

Comment: Oh, so simple xD I was looking for something like partitioning and sorting, but this improvement i think is definitely the best that we can do, if the number of objects is fixed.

Comment: @FalconUA: How are you so sure this is the best possible? It is a small improvement over what you posted initially, but I think there is a lot of room for improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried another idea with this problem: something like Quicksort. Given a set of items to sort in this manner, with potentially some partial information about order between elements, we try to find a good "pivot" near the middle of the set and then perform sorting operations which compare 4 other items to the pivot in order to separate the set into a subset less than the pivot and a subset greater than the pivot. We then sort each subset in a similar manner.

Initially we don't have any information about order, so we pick five elements at random and sort them. Then the middle item of those five is a good choice for a pivot. We can then continue with that pivot or revise our choice as more information comes in.

Below I have included Java classes to help visualize the process and to gather statistics on various methods for choosing the pivot. For a general overview of the classes, see my other answer. (I have improved them somewhat since then.) If you want to switch sorting methods, you have to edit the FiveSortPanel class.

Using the various different pivot methods seems to take between 16.85 and 16.95 steps on average, and never more than 20 steps (in the random sample I've taken). In addition, the method is very fast, using only linear time heuristics to find the pivot and the other four items to sort at each step.

Here's the revised GUI framework:

```
package org.jgrapht.demo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class FiveSort extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private Font smallFont = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 12);
  private Font largeFont = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 36);
  private JLabel stepsLabel = new JLabel("0");
  private JLabel maxLabel = new JLabel("0");
  private JLabel averageLabel = new JLabel("");
  private int rounds = 0;
  private int totalSteps = 0;
  private double averageSteps = 0;
  private int maxSteps = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new FiveSort();
      }
    });
  }

  public FiveSort() {
    initGUI();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Five Sort");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void initGUI() {
    try {
      // UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // title label
    JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Five Sort");
    titleLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    titleLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    titleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    titleLabel.setOpaque(true);
    titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    add(titleLabel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    // main panel 
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(mainPanel);

    // graph panel
    FiveSortPanel graphPanel = new FiveSortPanel();
    mainPanel.add(graphPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // stats panel
    JPanel statsPanel = new JPanel();
    statsPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    mainPanel.add(statsPanel);

    JLabel stepsTitleLabel = new JLabel("Current Steps: ");
    stepsTitleLabel.setFont(smallFont);
    stepsTitleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    statsPanel.add(stepsTitleLabel);
    stepsLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    stepsLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
    statsPanel.add(stepsLabel);

    JLabel maxTitleLabel = new JLabel("Max Steps: ");
    maxTitleLabel.setFont(smallFont);
    maxTitleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    statsPanel.add(maxTitleLabel);
    maxLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    maxLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    maxLabel.setText("" + maxSteps);
    statsPanel.add(maxLabel);

    JLabel averageTitleLabel = new JLabel("Avg Steps: ");
    averageTitleLabel.setFont(smallFont);
    averageTitleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    statsPanel.add(averageTitleLabel);
    averageLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    averageLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    averageLabel.setText("");
    statsPanel.add(averageLabel);

    // button panel
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    Button newButton = new Button("Step");
    newButton.setFocusable(false);
    newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!graphPanel.isComplete()) {
          graphPanel.step();
          stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
        }
      }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(newButton);

    Button restartButton = new Button("Restart");
    restartButton.setFocusable(false);
    restartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (graphPanel.isComplete()) {
          ++rounds;
          totalSteps += graphPanel.getSteps();
          averageSteps = ((int)(totalSteps / (double)rounds * 10))/10.0; 
          maxSteps = Math.max(maxSteps, graphPanel.getSteps());
        }
        graphPanel.restart();
        stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
        maxLabel.setText("" + maxSteps);
        averageLabel.setText("" + averageSteps);
      }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(restartButton);

    Button run50Button = new Button("Run 50");
    run50Button.setFocusable(false);
    run50Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int currentRounds = 0;
        while (currentRounds < 50) {
          if (!graphPanel.isComplete()) {
            graphPanel.step();
            stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
          } else {
            ++rounds;
            ++currentRounds;
            totalSteps += graphPanel.getSteps();
            averageSteps = ((int)(totalSteps / (double)rounds * 100))/100.0; 
            maxSteps = Math.max(maxSteps, graphPanel.getSteps());
            graphPanel.restart();
            stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
            maxLabel.setText("" + maxSteps);
            averageLabel.setText("" + averageSteps);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(run50Button);
  }

}
```

And here's the revised graph manipulation routines (which require jgrapht-ext-0.9.1-uber.jar, freely available from the JGraphT site):

```
package org.jgrapht.demo;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import org.jgrapht.DirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.Graphs;
import org.jgrapht.ListenableGraph;
import org.jgrapht.alg.StrongConnectivityInspector;
import org.jgrapht.alg.TransitiveClosure;
import org.jgrapht.ext.JGraphXAdapter;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.ListenableDirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleDirectedGraph;

import com.mxgraph.layout.mxCircleLayout;
import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.util.mxConstants;

public class FiveSortPanel extends JPanel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 25;
  private static final int SORT_SIZE = 5;
  private static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  private static final String STROKE_YELLOW = "strokeColor=#CCCC00";
  private Integer[][] BIBD = { 
    {1,2,3,4,5},     {6,7,8,9,10},    {11,12,13,14,15}, {16,17,18,19,20}, {21,22,23,24,0},
    {1,6,11,16,21},  {2,7,12,17,21},  {3,8,13,18,21},   {4,9,14,19,21},   {5,10,15,20,21},
    {2,8,14,20,22},  {3,10,11,19,22}, {5,9,12,16,22},   {1,7,15,18,22},   {4,6,13,17,22},
    {3,9,15,17,23},  {5,6,14,18,23},  {4,7,11,20,23},   {2,10,13,16,23},  {1,8,12,19,23},
    {4,10,12,18,24}, {1,9,13,20,24},  {2,6,15,19,24},   {5,8,11,17,24},   {3,7,14,16,24},
    {5,7,13,19,0},   {4,8,15,16,0},   {1,10,14,17,0},   {3,6,12,20,0},    {2,9,11,18,0}
  }; 
  private int steps = 0;
  private boolean complete = false;
  class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {
    String label;
    T value;
    Node(String label, T value) {
      this.label = label;
      this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return label + ": " + value.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node<T> other) {
      return value.compareTo(other.value);
    }
  }
  // g represents all potential orders; starts as complete graph
  private ListenableGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge> g;
  // g1 represents all actual orders; starts with no edges
  private SimpleDirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge> g1;
  private JGraphXAdapter<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge> jgxAdapter;
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Node<Integer>[] vertexArray = new Node[ARRAY_SIZE];
  List<Set<Node<Integer>>> connectedComponentsOfG;
  HashMap<Node<Integer>,com.mxgraph.model.mxICell> vertexToCellMap;
  HashMap<DefaultEdge,com.mxgraph.model.mxICell> edgeToCellMap;
  // sort sets in descending order by number of elements
  public class SetComparator implements Comparator<Set<Node<Integer>>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Set<Node<Integer>> s1, Set<Node<Integer>> s2) {
      return s2.size() - s1.size();
    }
  }
  TransitiveClosure transitiveClosure = TransitiveClosure.INSTANCE;
  public enum SortType { RANDOM_BIBD, PIVOT_LINEAR, PIVOT_QUADRATIC, PIVOT_RATIO };
  SortType sortType = SortType.PIVOT_RATIO;

  public FiveSortPanel() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(600,600);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    restart();
  }

  public int getSteps() {
    return steps;
  }

  public boolean isComplete() {
    return complete;
  }

  private void updateConnectedComponents() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    StrongConnectivityInspector<Node<Integer>,DefaultEdge> sci 
      = new StrongConnectivityInspector<Node<Integer>,DefaultEdge>(
          (DirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>) g);
    connectedComponentsOfG = sci.stronglyConnectedSets();
    Collections.sort(connectedComponentsOfG, new SetComparator());
  }

  public void step() {
    if (!complete) {
      chooseFiveAndSort();
      ++steps;
    }
    updateConnectedComponents();
    complete = true;
    for (Set<Node<Integer>> s : connectedComponentsOfG) {
      if (s.size() > 1) {
        complete = false;
      }
    }
  }

  public void restart() {
    removeAll();
    steps = 0;
    complete = false;
    if (sortType == SortType.RANDOM_BIBD) {
      shuffleBIBD();
    }
    g = new ListenableDirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    g1 = new SimpleDirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    jgxAdapter = new JGraphXAdapter<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>(g);
    vertexToCellMap = jgxAdapter.getVertexToCellMap();
    edgeToCellMap = jgxAdapter.getEdgeToCellMap();
    jgxAdapter.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle().put(mxConstants.STYLE_NOLABEL, "1");
    add(new mxGraphComponent(jgxAdapter));
    ArrayList<Integer> permutation = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
      permutation.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(permutation);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<Integer>[] n = new Node[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
      n[i] = new Node<Integer>(ALPHABET.substring(i, i+1), permutation.get(i));
      vertexArray[i] = n[i];
      g.addVertex(n[i]);
      g1.addVertex(n[i]);
      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        g.addEdge(n[i], n[j]);
        g.addEdge(n[j], n[i]);
      }
    }
    updateConnectedComponents();
    mxCircleLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(jgxAdapter);
    layout.execute(jgxAdapter.getDefaultParent());
    validate();
    repaint();
  }

  private void chooseFiveAndSort() {
    Node<Integer>[] fiveNodes = chooseFive();
    for (int i = 0; i < fiveNodes.length-1; ++i) {
      g1.addEdge(fiveNodes[i],fiveNodes[i+1]);
    }
    transitiveClosure.closeSimpleDirectedGraph(g1);
    List<Object> edgeCellList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fiveNodes.length-1; ++i) {
      List<Node<Integer>> predList = Graphs.predecessorListOf(g1,fiveNodes[i]);
      predList.add(fiveNodes[i]);
      List<Node<Integer>> succList = Graphs.successorListOf(g1,fiveNodes[i+1]);
      succList.add(fiveNodes[i+1]);
      for (Node<Integer> np : predList) {
        for (Node<Integer> ns : succList) {
          g.removeEdge(ns,np);
          edgeCellList.add((Object)(edgeToCellMap.get(g.getEdge(np, ns))));
        }
      }
    }
    if (edgeCellList != null) {
      jgxAdapter.setCellStyle(STROKE_YELLOW, edgeCellList.toArray());
    }
  }

  private void shuffleBIBD() {
    List<Integer[]> BIBDList = (List<Integer[]>) Arrays.asList(BIBD);
    Collections.shuffle(BIBDList);
    BIBD = BIBDList.toArray(new Integer[0][0]);
  }

  private Node<Integer>[] chooseFiveRandomBIBD() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<Integer>[] nodeArray = new Node[SORT_SIZE];
    Integer[] indexArray = BIBD[steps];
    for (int i = 0; i < SORT_SIZE; ++i) {
      nodeArray[i] = vertexArray[indexArray[i]];
    }
    Arrays.sort(nodeArray);
    return nodeArray;
  }

  private Node<Integer>[] chooseFive() {
    switch (sortType) {
    case RANDOM_BIBD:
      return chooseFiveRandomBIBD();
    case PIVOT_LINEAR:
      return chooseFivePivotLinear();
    case PIVOT_QUADRATIC:
      return chooseFivePivotQuadratic();
    case PIVOT_RATIO:
      return chooseFivePivotRatio();
    default:
      System.err.println("Internal error: unknown sorting method");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    return null; // inaccessible   
  }

  private Node<Integer>[] chooseFivePivotLinear() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<Integer>[] nodeArray = new Node[SORT_SIZE];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Set<Node<Integer>> largestSCC = 
      (Set<Node<Integer>>) (((HashSet<Node<Integer>>) connectedComponentsOfG.get(0)).clone());
    int s = largestSCC.size();
    if (s >= 5) {
      Node<Integer> pivot = largestSCC.iterator().next();
      int pivotDegree = g1.inDegreeOf(pivot) + g1.outDegreeOf(pivot);
      int pivotSymmetry = g1.inDegreeOf(pivot) - g1.outDegreeOf(pivot);
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        int nDegree = g1.inDegreeOf(n) + g1.outDegreeOf(n);
        int nSymmetry = g1.inDegreeOf(n) - g1.outDegreeOf(n);
        if (nDegree >= pivotDegree) {
          if (Math.abs(nSymmetry) < Math.abs(pivotSymmetry)) {
            pivot = n;
            pivotDegree = nDegree;
            pivotSymmetry = nSymmetry;
          }
        }
      }
      int chosen = 0;
      nodeArray[chosen++] = pivot;
      largestSCC.remove(pivot);
      int desiredConnections = 0;
      while (chosen < SORT_SIZE) {
        Iterator<Node<Integer>> iter = largestSCC.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
          Node<Integer> n = iter.next();
          int connectionsWithN = 0;
          for (Node<Integer> n1 : nodeArray) {
            if (g1.containsEdge(n,n1)) ++connectionsWithN;
            if (g1.containsEdge(n1,n)) ++connectionsWithN;
          }
          if (connectionsWithN <= desiredConnections) {
            nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
            iter.remove();
            if (chosen == SORT_SIZE) break;
          }
        }
        ++desiredConnections;
      }
    } else if (s == 4) { // take all 4 elements and 1 from elsewhere (which doesn't help)
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator().next();
    } else if (s == 3) { // take all 3 elements and find 2 from elsewhere
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      for (Set<Node<Integer>> scc : connectedComponentsOfG) { // prefer size 2 component
        if (scc.size() == 2) {
          for (Node<Integer> n : scc) {
            nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      if (chosen < SORT_SIZE) { // no size 2 component found 
        if (connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).size() == 3) { // take 2
          Iterator<Node<Integer>> iter = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = iter.next();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = iter.next();
        } else {
          nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator().next();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(2).iterator().next();
        }
      }
    } else if (s == 2) { // take both; all from next SCC, and 1 from next, and 1 more if nec. 
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      for (Node<Integer> n : connectedComponentsOfG.get(1)) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(2).iterator().next();
      if (connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).size() == 1) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(3).iterator().next();
      }
    } else if (s == 1) {
      System.err.println("Internal Error: should have been complete by now");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Arrays.sort(nodeArray);
    return nodeArray;
  } 

  private Node<Integer>[] chooseFivePivotQuadratic() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<Integer>[] nodeArray = new Node[SORT_SIZE];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Set<Node<Integer>> largestSCC = 
      (Set<Node<Integer>>) (((HashSet<Node<Integer>>) connectedComponentsOfG.get(0)).clone());
    int s = largestSCC.size();
    if (s >= 5) {
      Node<Integer> pivot = largestSCC.iterator().next();
      double pivotDegree = 7*g1.inDegreeOf(pivot) * g1.outDegreeOf(pivot) 
          - (g1.inDegreeOf(pivot)) * (g1.inDegreeOf(pivot))
          - (g1.outDegreeOf(pivot)) - (g1.outDegreeOf(pivot));
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        double nDegree = 7*g1.inDegreeOf(n) * g1.outDegreeOf(n) 
            - (g1.inDegreeOf(n)) * (g1.inDegreeOf(n))
            - (g1.outDegreeOf(n)) - (g1.outDegreeOf(n));
        if (nDegree >= pivotDegree) {
          pivot = n;
          pivotDegree = nDegree;
        }
      }
      int chosen = 0;
      nodeArray[chosen++] = pivot;
      largestSCC.remove(pivot);
      int desiredConnections = 0;
      while (chosen < SORT_SIZE) {
        Iterator<Node<Integer>> iter = largestSCC.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
          Node<Integer> n = iter.next();
          int connectionsWithN = 0;
          for (Node<Integer> n1 : nodeArray) {
            if (g1.containsEdge(n,n1)) ++connectionsWithN;
            if (g1.containsEdge(n1,n)) ++connectionsWithN;
          }
          if (connectionsWithN <= desiredConnections) {
            nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
            iter.remove();
            if (chosen == SORT_SIZE) break;
          }
        }
        ++desiredConnections;
      }
    } else if (s == 4) { // take all 4 elements and 1 from elsewhere (which doesn't help)
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator().next();
    } else if (s == 3) { // take all 3 elements and find 2 from elsewhere
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      for (Set<Node<Integer>> scc : connectedComponentsOfG) { // prefer size 2 component
        if (scc.size() == 2) {
          for (Node<Integer> n : scc) {
            nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      if (chosen < SORT_SIZE) { // no size 2 component found 
        if (connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).size() == 3) { // take 2
          Iterator<Node<Integer>> iter = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = iter.next();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = iter.next();
        } else {
          nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator().next();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(2).iterator().next();
        }
      }
    } else if (s == 2) { // take both; all from next SCC, and 1 from next, and 1 more if nec. 
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      for (Node<Integer> n : connectedComponentsOfG.get(1)) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(2).iterator().next();
      if (connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).size() == 1) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(3).iterator().next();
      }
    } else if (s == 1) {
      System.err.println("Internal Error: should have been complete by now");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Arrays.sort(nodeArray);
    return nodeArray;
  }

  private Node<Integer>[] chooseFivePivotRatio() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<Integer>[] nodeArray = new Node[SORT_SIZE];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Set<Node<Integer>> largestSCC = 
      (Set<Node<Integer>>) (((HashSet<Node<Integer>>) connectedComponentsOfG.get(0)).clone());
    int s = largestSCC.size();
    if (s >= 5) {
      Node<Integer> pivot = largestSCC.iterator().next();
      int pivotMinInOut = Math.min(g1.inDegreeOf(pivot),g1.outDegreeOf(pivot));
      int pivotMaxInOut = Math.max(g1.inDegreeOf(pivot),g1.outDegreeOf(pivot)); 
      double pivotRatio = (pivotMaxInOut == 0) ? 0 : pivotMinInOut/((double)pivotMaxInOut);
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        int nMinInOut = Math.min(g1.inDegreeOf(n),g1.outDegreeOf(n));
        int nMaxInOut = Math.max(g1.inDegreeOf(n),g1.outDegreeOf(n)); 
        double nRatio = (nMaxInOut == 0) ? 0 : nMinInOut/((double)nMaxInOut);
        if (nRatio > pivotRatio) {
          pivot = n;
          pivotRatio = nRatio;
        }
      }
      int chosen = 0;
      nodeArray[chosen++] = pivot;
      largestSCC.remove(pivot);
      int desiredConnections = 0;
      while (chosen < SORT_SIZE) {
        Iterator<Node<Integer>> iter = largestSCC.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
          Node<Integer> n = iter.next();
          int connectionsWithN = 0;
          for (Node<Integer> n1 : nodeArray) {
            if (g1.containsEdge(n,n1)) ++connectionsWithN;
            if (g1.containsEdge(n1,n)) ++connectionsWithN;
          }
          if (connectionsWithN <= desiredConnections) {
            nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
            iter.remove();
            if (chosen == SORT_SIZE) break;
          }
        }
        ++desiredConnections;
      }
    } else if (s == 4) { // take all 4 elements and 1 from elsewhere (which doesn't help)
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator().next();
    } else if (s == 3) { // take all 3 elements and find 2 from elsewhere
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      for (Set<Node<Integer>> scc : connectedComponentsOfG) { // prefer size 2 component
        if (scc.size() == 2) {
          for (Node<Integer> n : scc) {
            nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
          }
          break;
        }
      }
      if (chosen < SORT_SIZE) { // no size 2 component found 
        if (connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).size() == 3) { // take 2
          Iterator<Node<Integer>> iter = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = iter.next();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = iter.next();
        } else {
          nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).iterator().next();
          nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(2).iterator().next();
        }
      }
    } else if (s == 2) { // take both; all from next SCC, and 1 from next, and 1 more if nec. 
      int chosen = 0;
      for (Node<Integer> n : largestSCC) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      for (Node<Integer> n : connectedComponentsOfG.get(1)) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = n;
      }
      nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(2).iterator().next();
      if (connectedComponentsOfG.get(1).size() == 1) {
        nodeArray[chosen++] = connectedComponentsOfG.get(3).iterator().next();
      }
    } else if (s == 1) {
      System.err.println("Internal Error: should have been complete by now");
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Arrays.sort(nodeArray);
    return nodeArray;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

One interesting angle on this question is the idea of using "combinatorial block designs". We want each of our sorts to give us as much information as possible, so we don't want the same pair of elements in two different sorts. That is actually achievable: we can use a combinatorial structure called a "balanced incomplete block design" (BIBD). We are looking for a (25,5,1)-BIBD, meaning there are 25 elements (25), blocked by five at a time (5), such that each pair of elements appears in exactly one block (1).

Such block designs have been extensively explored. It turns out that there is a (25,5,1)-BIBD. An explicit construction is given in, e.g., http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0909/0909.3533.pdf page 8.

```
{(1,2,3,4,5) (6,7,8,9,10) (11,12,13,14,15) (16,17,18,19,20) (21,22,23,24,25)
(1,6,11,16,21) (2,7,12,17,21) (3,8,13,18,21) (4,9,14,19,21) (5,10,15,20,21)
(2,8,14,20,22) (3,10,11,19,22) (5,9,12,16,22) (1,7,15,18,22) (4,6,13,17,22)
(3,9,15,17,23) (5,6,14,18,23) (4,7,11,20,23) (2,10,13,16,23) (1,8,12,19,23)
(4,10,12,18,24) (1,9,13,20,24) (2,6,15,19,24) (5,8,11,17,24) (3,7,14,16,24)
(5,7,13,19,25) (4,8,15,16,25) (1,10,14,17,25) (3,6,12,20,25) (2,9,11,18,25)}
```

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) can also be used to construct BIBDs.

That block design has 30 blocks, so it's far from optimal for this problem. But perhaps it can be combined with transitivity to devise a faster algorithm for the problem.

**Update**

It turns out that my suggestion is not much use in this problem, except to place an upper bound on the number of steps in a solution (30, the size of the BIBD). To gauge its performance, I wrote some "test bed" software (see below) which gives a visual representation of  the progress of the sort.

I represented the state of sortedness of the data with two graphs: g, the graph of all potential relationships among the 25 items, which starts as a complete directed graph on the 25 items, and g1, the graph of all known relationships among the 25 items. g and g1 have an obvious relationship, so keeping track of two graphs is clearly redundant, but different kinds of information can be easily extracted from g and g1 which I why I keep track of them both.

g starts with 600 edges, each of the 25*24 directed edges between two items. We are done when g has no non-trivial (i.e., size greater than 1) strongly connected components, in which case g can be unambiguously toposorted to give the correct ordering. That occurs when there are exactly 300 edges in g. Similarly, g1 starts with no edges, and we are done when the same 300 edges appear in g1 as in g.

Picking 5 items and then sorting them immediately adds up to 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 15 new edges to g (and removes the same number of edges from g1). I say "up to" because if any of those edges are already in g, they don't get added to the count. So if we already know A -> B and nothing about relationships between any other pair in A,B,C,D,E, then sorting those five only gives 14 new edges in g.

On the other hand, we can often get more arrows from a sort by exploiting transitivity. If we know that B -> F, and a sort tells us that A -> B, we can deduce that A -> F, which is an extra arrow in g. The set of all additional arrows found through transitivity can be obtained by finding the "transitive closure" of g with the new arrows added as a result of the sort. The corresponding effect on g1 can be easily found.

In my software below, I give an image of the graph g1, which starts out as 600 directed edges pictured as 300 blue edges with arrows on each end. Each sorting step followed by transitive closure will replace some doubled-sided blue arrows with single-sided yellow arrows. We know we're finished when all the blue arrows are gone; equivalently, when g1 has no non-trivial strongly connected components.

In the software below, I chose the 5 items to be sorted by picking a random unused block from the BIBD I gave earlier, then marked the block as used. It generally takes all 30 blocks to sort the 25 items in this manner. As you can see from the visualization, the process starts out well enough, but misses obvious speedups from steps 20 to 30. My conclusion is that the fastest solutions to this problem will have to be adaptive, picking 5 items to sort based on prior results.

Looking at the problem in this way has given me some new ideas that I may explore in another answer to the question. In the meantime, here are the two Java classes  for the program I used.

The GUI framework:

```
package org.jgrapht.demo;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class FiveSort extends JFrame {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private Font smallFont = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 12);
  private Font largeFont = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 36);
  private JLabel stepsLabel = new JLabel("0");
  private JLabel maxLabel = new JLabel("0");
  private JLabel averageLabel = new JLabel("");
  private int rounds = 0;
  private int totalSteps = 0;
  private double averageSteps = 0;
  private int maxSteps = 0;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        new FiveSort();
      }
    });
  }

  public FiveSort() {
    initGUI();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Five Sort");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public void initGUI() {
    try {
      // UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // title label
    JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Five Sort");
    titleLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    titleLabel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    titleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    titleLabel.setOpaque(true);
    titleLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    add(titleLabel,BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    // main panel 
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    add(mainPanel);

    // graph panel
    FiveSortPanel graphPanel = new FiveSortPanel();
    mainPanel.add(graphPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // stats panel
    JPanel statsPanel = new JPanel();
    statsPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    mainPanel.add(statsPanel);

    JLabel stepsTitleLabel = new JLabel("Current Steps: ");
    stepsTitleLabel.setFont(smallFont);
    stepsTitleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    statsPanel.add(stepsTitleLabel);
    stepsLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    stepsLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
    statsPanel.add(stepsLabel);

    JLabel maxTitleLabel = new JLabel("Max Steps: ");
    maxTitleLabel.setFont(smallFont);
    maxTitleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    statsPanel.add(maxTitleLabel);
    maxLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    maxLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    maxLabel.setText("" + maxSteps);
    statsPanel.add(maxLabel);

    JLabel averageTitleLabel = new JLabel("Avg Steps: ");
    averageTitleLabel.setFont(smallFont);
    averageTitleLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    statsPanel.add(averageTitleLabel);
    averageLabel.setFont(largeFont);
    averageLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    averageLabel.setText("");
    statsPanel.add(averageLabel);

    // button panel
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    add(buttonPanel,BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    Button newButton = new Button("Step");
    newButton.setFocusable(false);
    newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!graphPanel.isComplete()) {
          graphPanel.step();
          stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
        }
      }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(newButton);

    Button restartButton = new Button("Restart");
    restartButton.setFocusable(false);
    restartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (graphPanel.isComplete()) {
          ++rounds;
          totalSteps += graphPanel.getSteps();
          averageSteps = ((int)(totalSteps / (double)rounds * 10))/10.0; 
          maxSteps = Math.max(maxSteps, graphPanel.getSteps());
        }
        graphPanel.restart();
        stepsLabel.setText("" + graphPanel.getSteps());
        maxLabel.setText("" + maxSteps);
        averageLabel.setText("" + averageSteps);
      }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(restartButton);
  }

}
```

The graph manipulation routines (which require jgrapht-ext-0.9.1-uber.jar, freely available from the JGraphT site):

```
package org.jgrapht.demo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.jgrapht.DirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.Graphs;
import org.jgrapht.ListenableGraph;
import org.jgrapht.alg.StrongConnectivityInspector;
import org.jgrapht.alg.TransitiveClosure;
import org.jgrapht.ext.JGraphXAdapter;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;
import org.jgrapht.graph.ListenableDirectedGraph;
import org.jgrapht.graph.SimpleDirectedGraph;

import com.mxgraph.layout.mxCircleLayout;
import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.util.mxConstants;

public class FiveSortPanel extends JPanel {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 25;
  private static final int SORT_SIZE = 5;
  private static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  private static final String STROKE_YELLOW = "strokeColor=#CCCC00";
  private Integer[][] BIBD = { 
    {1,2,3,4,5},     {6,7,8,9,10},    {11,12,13,14,15}, {16,17,18,19,20}, {21,22,23,24,0},
    {1,6,11,16,21},  {2,7,12,17,21},  {3,8,13,18,21},   {4,9,14,19,21},   {5,10,15,20,21},
    {2,8,14,20,22},  {3,10,11,19,22}, {5,9,12,16,22},   {1,7,15,18,22},   {4,6,13,17,22},
    {3,9,15,17,23},  {5,6,14,18,23},  {4,7,11,20,23},   {2,10,13,16,23},  {1,8,12,19,23},
    {4,10,12,18,24}, {1,9,13,20,24},  {2,6,15,19,24},   {5,8,11,17,24},   {3,7,14,16,24},
    {5,7,13,19,0},   {4,8,15,16,0},   {1,10,14,17,0},   {3,6,12,20,0},    {2,9,11,18,0}
  }; 
  private int steps = 0;
  private boolean complete = false;
  class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {
    String label;
    T value;
    Node(String label, T value) {
      this.label = label;
      this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return label + ": " + value.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node<T> other) {
      return value.compareTo(other.value);
    }
  }
  // g represents all potential orders; starts as complete graph
  private ListenableGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge> g;
  // g1 represents all actual orders; starts with no edges
  private SimpleDirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge> g1;
  private JGraphXAdapter<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge> jgxAdapter;
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  Node<Integer>[] vertexArray = new Node[ARRAY_SIZE];
  List<Set<Node<Integer>>> connectedComponentsOfG;
  HashMap<Node<Integer>,com.mxgraph.model.mxICell> vertexToCellMap;
  HashMap<DefaultEdge,com.mxgraph.model.mxICell> edgeToCellMap;
  // sort sets in descending order by number of elements
  public class SetComparator implements Comparator<Set<Node<Integer>>> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Set<Node<Integer>> s1, Set<Node<Integer>> s2) {
      return s2.size() - s1.size();
    }
  }
  TransitiveClosure transitiveClosure = TransitiveClosure.INSTANCE;

  public FiveSortPanel() {
    restart();
  }

  public int getSteps() {
    return steps;
  }

  public boolean isComplete() {
    return complete;
  }

  private void updateConnectedComponents() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    StrongConnectivityInspector<Node<Integer>,DefaultEdge> sci 
      = new StrongConnectivityInspector<Node<Integer>,DefaultEdge>(
          (DirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>) g);
    connectedComponentsOfG = sci.stronglyConnectedSets();
    Collections.sort(connectedComponentsOfG, new SetComparator());
  }

  public void step() {
    if (!complete) {
      chooseFiveAndSort();
      ++steps;
    }
    updateConnectedComponents();
    complete = true;
    for (Set<Node<Integer>> s : connectedComponentsOfG) {
      if (s.size() > 1) {
        complete = false;
      }
    }
  }

  public void restart() {
    removeAll();
    steps = 0;
    complete = false;
    shuffleBIBD();
    g = new ListenableDirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    g1 = new SimpleDirectedGraph<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);
    jgxAdapter = new JGraphXAdapter<Node<Integer>, DefaultEdge>(g);
    vertexToCellMap = jgxAdapter.getVertexToCellMap();
    edgeToCellMap = jgxAdapter.getEdgeToCellMap();
    jgxAdapter.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle().put(mxConstants.STYLE_NOLABEL, "1");
    add(new mxGraphComponent(jgxAdapter));
    ArrayList<Integer> permutation = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
      permutation.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(permutation);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<Integer>[] n = new Node[ARRAY_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
      n[i] = new Node<Integer>(ALPHABET.substring(i, i+1), permutation.get(i));
      vertexArray[i] = n[i];
      g.addVertex(n[i]);
      g1.addVertex(n[i]);
      for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        g.addEdge(n[i], n[j]);
        g.addEdge(n[j], n[i]);
      }
    }
    updateConnectedComponents();
    mxCircleLayout layout = new mxCircleLayout(jgxAdapter);
    layout.execute(jgxAdapter.getDefaultParent());
    //repaint();
  }

  private void chooseFiveAndSort() {
    Node<Integer>[] fiveNodes = chooseFive();
    for (int i = 0; i < fiveNodes.length-1; ++i) {
      g1.addEdge(fiveNodes[i],fiveNodes[i+1]);
    }
    transitiveClosure.closeSimpleDirectedGraph(g1);
    List<Object> edgeCellList = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < fiveNodes.length-1; ++i) {
      List<Node<Integer>> predList = Graphs.predecessorListOf(g1,fiveNodes[i]);
      predList.add(fiveNodes[i]);
      List<Node<Integer>> succList = Graphs.successorListOf(g1,fiveNodes[i+1]);
      succList.add(fiveNodes[i+1]);
      for (Node<Integer> np : predList) {
        for (Node<Integer> ns : succList) {
          g.removeEdge(ns,np);
          edgeCellList.add((Object)(edgeToCellMap.get(g.getEdge(np, ns))));
        }
      }
    }
    jgxAdapter.setCellStyle(STROKE_YELLOW, edgeCellList.toArray());
  }

  private Node<Integer>[] chooseFive() {
    return chooseFiveRandomBIBD();
  }

  private void shuffleBIBD() {
    List<Integer[]> BIBDList = (List<Integer[]>) Arrays.asList(BIBD);
    Collections.shuffle(BIBDList);
    BIBD = BIBDList.toArray(new Integer[0][0]);
  }

  private Node<Integer>[] chooseFiveRandomBIBD() {
    Integer[] indexArray = BIBD[steps];
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Node<Integer>[] nodeArray = new Node[SORT_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SORT_SIZE; ++i) {
      nodeArray[i] = vertexArray[indexArray[i]];
    }
    Arrays.sort(nodeArray);
    return nodeArray;
  }

}
```

Comment: The construction is simple enough that you don't need to look it up. It's the affine plane over the integers mod 5. Points are (x,y) x and y are integers mod 5. Lines are sets of the form ax+by=1 where a and b are integers mod 5, not both divisible by 5. As you point out, this is not optimal. It could be a big restriction to pick the possible sets of 5 ahead of time instead of dynamically based on past results. In some similar problems, picking the sets ahead of time only loses a constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

Let's partition all elements in 5 groups by 5 elements , remove last 2 elements from each group (these numbers are less than 3 numbers and coudln't for sure be candidates for the solution). We do the same procedure multiple times till we come with one group with 5 elements which sort for the last time and take the first three elements of it as a solution.

**Here is the count of sort operation**

```
5 groups by 5 elements - 5 sort
25 - 10 = 15 elements in 3 groups - 3 sort
15 - 6 = 9 elements in 2 groups ( one with 4 elements, the other with 5 elements) - 1 sort
4 + 3 = 7 elements in 2 groups ( one with 5 and one with 2 element) 1 sort
3 + 2 = 5 elements 1 sort
Total count: 5 + 3 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 11 sort
```